# Magento 2 Catalog Search ElasticSearch Resave All Products Issue

Tags: magento2, php, database, elasticsearch

I have a Magento 2.2.2 site - hosted on a dedicated server, linux centos6, apache, nginx, which is running fine however I have had to delete and re-import attribute manufacturer - brand - all entries have been imported ok however they are not showing on front end in the layered navigation.

I have since found that changing the Stores/Configuration,Catalog Search/Search Engine setting from ElasticSearch to MySQL and refresh cache all brands are showing in Layered Navigation and All Brands Page.

I then changed the setting back to ElasticSearch and Went to some products and without making any changes just resaved via Admin and cleared cache and now the ones resaved are showing on frontend.

I have also found that they will only show on front end if resaved via Admin and not by any other method.

This is a very strange issue and wasted 3 days on it already.

I exported original without resaving and also resaved products via import/export, and all settings seem to be same in the exported file for those products resaved.

So I am assuming it is some value being changed in Database which can only be done when saved via Admin.

I tried to create another test attribute and do mass update changing the value and hoping it will resave all attributes once again but I got the error
something went wrong when saving the attributes.

Can anyone provide any suggestion into what is causing this issue and how to fix and avoid it in future,

Thank You